# Is it possible to change the value of a variable during execution time?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

I want to know if there is any way I can change the value of a variable during execution time, using Visual Studio 2008? I know I can do this on Eclipse (put a breakpoint, add a watcher and edit whatever variable value  I want) but I didn't find this feature on VS yet?

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

In VS if you hover your mouse over this variable, you'll notice it displays it's value in a tooltip.  You can click into this tooltip and edit it manually - though you need to provide a value of the correct format for the data type.  Strings also need quotes "".

There is likely a way to do this via some of the other debugging windows, but I don't know of any.  I'll leave those answers to someone else.

Answer (score 22):

In VS, there is the [command/immediate window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c785s0kz.aspx) (when debugging, under the Debug -> Windows menu) which allows you to change variable values.

A more visual way is the [Variable window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa6fy2x5.aspx).

Comment: Used this for `datetime` with `AddDays`, where needed to get a date in future. When using the tooltip, got a syntax error.

Answer (score 11):

Use the [Immediate Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/immediate-window?view=vs-2019).

> Use the Immediate window to debug and evaluate expressions, execute
>   statements, and print variable values. The Immediate window evaluates
>   expressions by building and using the currently selected project.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  There are several Ways.

Double-click the variables value in the Watch, Local or Auto's window.  You can also do this from the immediate window.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it using one of the following ways

- User Immediate window
- Using quickwatch window

Both allow user to change the variables value.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this as follows:
1. Put a breakpoint just after the line of code where you want to update the varaible value.
2. Run the application till the breakpoint is hit.
3. Just hover over the variable you want to edit and the varable name and value will be shown.
4. Click on the Value field and edit it, press enter.

Mission accomplished...

Comment: For a String as we are able to change only address or first char.. Any possible way to change complete string?

Answer (score 0):

When the code is stopped, there are many ways to change the value as answers here suggest. But there is also a way to change it **without code stop or code modification**.

For example, I needed to create a condition that would start throwing errors or write log messages. I did not want to modify the code. What I did, I inserted a **Tracepoint** and assigned an invalid value to a variable, which later was throwing an error. And for testing multi-threaded code, when you don't want to stop, this is perfect. The only downside, the value is written to the *Output* window.

[image]